# SQL/BigQuery: switching/swapping row values between two columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Summary of the problem:**

I have a BigQuery SQL table formatted as such:

| Source | Target | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | C | 2 |
| D | A | 3 |
| E | A | 4 |

I am trying to rearrange the table so that, e.g., all the `A` values will be moved to the `Source` column and out of the `Target` column, with the expected result:

| Source | Target | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| A | C | 2 |
| A | D | 3 |
| A | E | 4 |

I can do this for a *single* value, but my problem is, I want to shift the `Source` and `Target` values for *multiple* values.

In reality, the weights are Jaccard similarity coefficients between two sets. They were estimated in BigQuery, but because they were not estimated in a pairwise fashion given BigQuery's tabular format, values I'd expect to be in the `Source` column appear in the `Target` column.

**What I've tried:**

For a single value, e.g., `A` only, I have the following solution:

```
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT  
        *, "A" AS new_source 
    FROM networks.my_table
    WHERE `Source`= "A" OR `Target` = "A"
    ORDER BY jaccard DESC
),
output AS (
    SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN `Target` = new_source THEN `Source` ELSE `Target` END new_target
    FROM temp
)
SELECT * FROM output
```

But I cannot seem to generalize this for all cases.

Alternatively, if there is a way to transform the data into a matrix before applying the Jaccard coefficient estimates, I would accept that solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select if(Target = 'A', struct(Target as Source, Source as Target, Weight), t).*
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail! This works for a single known value, but not for generalizing across the whole table. I think it has to do with how the data is structured. I opened up a new question here that is more relevant to that point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352496/unique-pairs-of-non-repeating-values-in-sql