# Unique pairs of non-repeating values in SQL

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

**The problem:**

I have a BigQuery SQL table formatted as such:

| group | users |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,2,3 |
| B | 1,5,3 |
| C | 3,6,1 |
| D | 0,1,2 |

I would like to find all possible unique pairs between each group and users, such that the table will be formatted this way:

| group1 | group2 | group1_users | group2_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1,2,3 | 1,5,3 |
| A | C | 1,2,3 | 3,6,1 |
| A | D | 1,2,3 | 0,1,2 |
| B | C | 1,5,3 | 3,6,1 |
| B | D | 1,5,3 | 0,1,2 |
| C | D | 3,6,1 | 0,1,2 |

I do not want repeating inverse pairs. So, if pair `A,B` already exists across columns `group1` and `group2` respectively, I *do not* want pair `B,A` to be an option.

**What I've tried:**

I'm stumped on how to accomplish this. I've tried modifying code from other posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938232/how-to-find-unique-pairs-from-two-columns-in-sql), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161901/select-pairs-a-b-excluding-b-a-with-same-value/161904), etc.) to no avail.

Comment: What logic do you use to determine that `A,B` wins out over `B,A`? Is it just that, lexicographically, `A` is first and therefore wins the first position in your tuple?

Comment: Yes, there is no logic other than the order of observation. I can sort the values alphabetically, but it is based on the first observation. Order doesn't actually matter that much here, just preventing duplicates.  If I could transform the data into a pairwise matrix, that'd be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query returns what you are looking for:

```
with my_data as (
select "A" as _group, [1,2,3] as users
UNION ALL
select "B" as _group, [1,5,3] as users
UNION ALL
select "C" as _group, [3,6,1] as users
UNION ALL
select "D" as _group, [0,1,2] as users
)

SELECT 
  l._group as _group_1, 
  r._group _group_2, 
  l.users as group1_users, 
  r.users group1_users, 
FROM my_data l 
  JOIN my_data r 
  ON l._group < r._group
```

[image]